# attach several images to post + gallery

Tags: images, posts, post-thumbnails, gallery

i'm wondering if its possible to attach several images to a post then display those images in a thumbnail/fading gallery?

By the way, the images should also be resized to a fixed size + thumbnail.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the standard wordpress [gallery] shortcode, after having attacched the images to your post.

To attach images to your post, you can use the button "Upload Media".

Upload the image from your disk and the press "Save Changes". The image will be attached to your post.

Then use the [gallery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) shortcode to insert the gallery in your post.

Comment: thanks a lot! and how can i display only text without the images? im getting the images via get_children() thx